# Google Maps API circle markers, variable size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

```js
var xml = data.responseXML;
var circles = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("location");
    var scans = markers[i].getAttribute("scans");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("long")));
    var html = name;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      center: center,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,
   map: map,
   radius:1000
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
```

Trying to add some data to circle markers.

The circles are already markers for specific locations, but I want to make them vary in size depending on a count that corresponds to that location.  I cannot seem to find any code to make markers of variable size, since each marker is most likely going to have a unique number of contacts. Any ideas?

Here's the code I have now for markers.  I know its not right, since it's not producing what I want.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple    <---This is the effect that I am looking for, but I don't understand how to get the values for size to change based on the data entered in the table.

Comment: some links to get you started:
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Comment: What does your code look like currently?   How are you currently creating the markers?  Are  you trying to do something like [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)?

Comment: I've seen that example you mention @geocodezip, but these values for how big I want the circles will change as more data is entered into our linked table.  I'm wondering if I can make the size a variable - to pull the size information each time the map is made.

Comment: The radius of those circles is determined by the data.  How are you planning on determining the radius of your circles?

Comment: @geocodezip I have a table in which stores the count of contacts for each location.  That number is what I want the size to be based on.  but that number will always be changing as more data is entered into the table. That's the problem I'm having. I want the sizes to update without having to go in and change the code all the time.  I'm not sure if thats the answer to your question; I'm very new to coding and have been learning through examples I've found.

Comment: What does your XML look like?  What attribute determines the size of the circles?  Are you using `google.maps.Circle` objects or `google.maps.Marker` objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the marker radius to an integer returned by a function. Or it can be an expression.

Here is a JsFiddle with a working example where the count attribute in the XML is set by an expression.

```
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6685771, -122.2553681),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
        var marker = markers[i];
        var name = marker.getAttribute("location");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(marker.getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(marker.getAttribute("long")));
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: point,
            radius: marker.getAttribute("count") * 75
        });
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/plbogen/ecj8o4uL

Comment: getting closer, but not quite right yet. probably on my end. thanks for your help!

Comment: The [MarkersOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object is not correct, it is a [CircleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions) object.

Comment: I just copied his code and made the change to radius originally. I now have working code with a jsfiddle to show.